# iOS: Loading a website into a webview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am trying to load a website into a webview which I've been able to do before. But I can't seem to get it to load correctly. I have looked all over Stack and other forums for a solution but I can't seem to figure it out.

My .h file is as follows:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ScheduleView : ViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webview;

@end
```

and my .m:

```
#import "ScheduleView.h"

@interface ScheduleView ()
@end
@implementation ScheduleView

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *urlstring = @"http://www.google.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlstring];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_webview loadRequest:urlRequest];

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

@end
```

Whenever I try to run my application, it will launch as intended but when I navigate to the ViewController containing the WebView, it will just show a blank screen. And I have tried to use other websites other than google.

This is my first time posting so if I need to give more information, please let me know and I will do my best to reply swiftly.

EDIT:

After putting in the break point on

```
[super viewDidLoad];
```

it did come back "nil"

[Breakpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgDRN.png)

What does this mean? How do I fix it?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `viewDidLoad` and verify that `_webview` is not `nil`. Make sure your outlet is connected.

Comment: BTW - you have a property, use it. Change `[_webview loadRequest:urlRequest];` to `[self.webview loadRequest:urlRequest];`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using http://www.google.com You might see below error in your logs

Transport security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.

use solution provided here [Transport security has blocked a cleartext HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http)

Answer (score 0):

add these to your `info.plist` and try

[image]

and make sure, that you have created the connection between your `webview` and `.h` file